How can I extend a module config schema in another module?
In Drupal 11, I have written a custom key provider for the key module. This adds a new key provider, per_user.
However, when I run a test that installs the module on GitLab CI, I get an error:
Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: Schema errors for key.key.per_user with the following errors: key.key.per_user:key_provider_settings missing schema
So I tried to define the schema.
key.schema.yml contains a schema for each key provider included with the module:
key.provider.file:
  type: mapping
  label: 'File key provider settings'
  mapping:
    file_location:
      type: string
      label: 'File location'
    base64_encoded:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Base64-encoded'
    strip_line_breaks:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Strip trailing line breaks'

key.provider.env:
  type: mapping
  label: 'Environment key provider settings'
  mapping:
    env_variable:
      type: string
      label: 'Environment variable'
    base64_encoded:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Base64-encoded'
    strip_line_breaks:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Strip trailing line breaks'

My custom key provider should have a schema like this:
key.provider.per_user:
  type: mapping
  label: 'Per user key provider settings'
  mapping:
    base64_encoded:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Base64-encoded'
    strip_line_breaks:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Strip trailing line breaks'

But I don't know where to put this schema. How do I extend the base module's config schema to include the one for my custom key provider?

Wouldn’t you just put it in foo/config/schema/foo.schema.yml (with foo being the module machine name)?

As suggested by Clive, even though it is extending another module's config definition, you can put it in mymodule/config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml.
The reason that this didn't work for me is that I was using a different provider name (my schema referenced per_user, but the annotation defined it as per_user_key).
